# How to toggle enable/disable a checkbox in a row of a table by clicking a button in the same row

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

In a table, each row has a `button` and a `checkbox`. On click of the button I want to toggle the enable/disable state of the `checkbox` (Not the checked value). My approach is actually toggling the enable/disable state for all the `checkbox` in the table, however I want the affect for only the particular row.

```cs
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var eachData in dataList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button @onclick="HandleToggleEvent">@SelectionButtonLabel</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>eachData.val1</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" @bind="eachData.IsChecked" disabled=@(!IsRowSelected)>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
```

```cs
@code {
    private bool IsRowSelected { get; set; }
    private string SelectionButtonLabel = "Edit";

    private void HandleToggleEvent()
    {
        if (!IsRowSelected)
        {
            IsRowSelected = true;
            SelectionButtonLabel = "Cancel";
        }
        else
        {
            IsRowSelected = false;
            SelectionButtonLabel = "Edit";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an indexer instead.

```
private List<string> dataList = new List<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three" };

private List<bool> IsRowSelected { get; set; } = new List<bool>();
private string SelectionButtonLabel = "Edit";

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    foreach (var item in dataList) IsRowSelected.Add(false);
}

private void HandleToggleEvent(int idx)
{
    if (!IsRowSelected[idx])
    {
        IsRowSelected[idx] = true;
        SelectionButtonLabel = "Cancel";
    }
    else
    {
        IsRowSelected[idx] = false;
        SelectionButtonLabel = "Edit";
    }
}
```

Don't forget to initialize the list and populate it with values for each value in `dataList`.  Then, in your razor code:

```
 <tbody>
     @for (int i = 0; i < dataList.Count; i++)
     {
         int idx = i; //This is important to avoid closing on i;
         <tr>
             <td>
                <button @onclick="() => HandleToggleEvent(idx)">@SelectionButtonLabel</button>
             </td>
             <td>dataList[i].val1</td>
             <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" disabled="@(!IsRowSelected[idx])">
             </td>
         </tr>
      }
</tbody>
```

Then you need to do the same with SelectionButtonLabel.